# update statement doesn't do anything to my table

Tags: php, sql

I get no errors and all my print statements are telling me i'm doing a good job, yet my field under the desired column stay the same.

what is happening (or rather not happening)?

```
if ($current && $new) {// the validation code is left out


        $sqlTekst = "UPDATE gebruikers SET pasW  = ". $_POST[nieuwPasw] ." WHERE gebruikersNr = ". $_POST[gebruikersNr];
        print 'huidig POST gebruikersNr = $_POST[gebruikersNr]';

// server koppeling
        $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "internet", "geheim");
// database koppeling
        mysql_select_db("site_met_aanmelden", $db)
                or die("Kan database gebruikers niet openen".mysql_error());        
        $resultaat = mysql_query($sqlTekst, $db);
        }
```

Comment: How are you verifying that you are running the script and that the data is being updated?

Answer (score 1):

Did you 'commit' the database changes?

Comment: All I did was check my table in phpMyadmin doing a query. I don't really know what you mean by 'commit'

Comment: Doesn't look like he had set autocommit to false.

Comment: MySQL auto-commits a single query by default if table created w/ InnoDB engine. I don't know any person who changes this behaviour.

Comment: @Nemoden: mysql auto-commits all queries, regardless of tabletype, unless you specifically disable the behavior or explicitly start a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

add error handling for the actual query execution
take care of possible sql injections
check affected rows to see whether your WHERE-condition works or not
format and indent your sql statement and you'll get a slightly more meaningful error message
print your sql statement so you can check all of the parameters
use $array['string'] instead of $array[string]

```
if ($current && $new) { // the validation code is left out
  $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "internet", "geheim") or die("connect failed. ".mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("site_met_aanmelden", $db) or die("Kan database gebruikers niet openen".mysql_error());

  $sql_pasW = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nieuwPasw'], $db);
  $sql_gebruikersNr = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gebruikersNr'], $db);

  $sqlTekst = sprintf("
    UPDATE
      gebruikers
    SET
      pasW='%s'
    WHERE
      gebruikersNr ='%s'
    ", $sql_pasW, $sql_gebruikersNr
  );
  echo 'Debug '.__FILE__.__LINE__.': ', $sqlTekst, "\n"; 
  $resultaat = mysql_query($sqlTekst, $db) or die('query failed: '.mysql_error());

  echo 'affected rows: ', mysql_affected_rows($db);
}
```

Comment: That looks tight and useful stuff. Gonna have to check this tomorrow haven't had the time today. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I assume at least of your `$_POST['nieuwPasw']` or `$_POST['gebruikersNr']` is string and you don't enclose it with ' in your query.

Your working query would be

```
$sqlTekst = "UPDATE gebruikers SET pasW  = '". $_POST['nieuwPasw'] ."' WHERE gebruikersNr = '". $_POST['gebruikersNr']."'";
```

Just replace a string.

you can also get information if there error emerged in your query by using [mysql_error](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)  function.

Add

```
if (!$resultaat) {
echo mysql_error();
}
```

this would print error occured during query.

I'd also suggest to enclose arrays keys in apostrophs (double or singular  - does not really matter).

Comment: Yes but the thing is I do not get any error. 
And for the ' I've done both and in both cases my table doesn't get updated

Comment: Oh alright why didn't think of that the mysql error could be so widely applicable. Makes perfect sense. Interestingly enough: Error says there's something wrong near " at line 1. The code I posted starts at line 28....

Comment: $_POST['gebruikersNr'] is not set? :) just do `print $sqlTekst`, you'll probably see that. And don't forget to share here if your problem remains unsolved.

Comment: $_POST[$'gebruikersNr'] is definitely set :-) And yes I verified that by doing that same print `$sqlTekst`

Comment: And forgot to share `print $sqlTekst` results ;)

Comment: ...And thanks Nemoden for reminding me. It does say the actual value of the 'gebruikersNr' :-)

Comment: Then format/indent the sql statement so the mysql server can tell you the exact line and print the whole statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would fix it as follows:

```
$sqlTekst = "UPDATE gebruikers SET pasW  = '". $_POST["nieuwPasw"] ."' WHERE gebruikersNr = ". $_POST["gebruikersNr"];
```

Assuming your `Nr` refers to number which doesn't need quotes in the select.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that:

```
 $sqlTekst = "UPDATE gebruikers SET pasW  = '". $_POST[nieuwPasw] ."' WHERE gebruikersNr = '". $_POST[gebruikersNr]."'";
```